# In which layer is HTTP in the OSI model?

Tags: http, http2, osi

Some said HTTP is in the session layer in the OSI model.

But in Tanenbaum's Computer Network, HTTP is said to be in the application layer in the OSI model.

Also some said that HTTP has no concept of session. Does it mean that HTTP can't be in the session layer?

So is HTTP in the session layer? Thanks.

Update: For HTTP/2 what is the layer in OSI model?

Comment: just because both specs use the word  "session" doesn't mean session means the same thing in both. it's a synonym.

Comment: HTTP is in the Application layer of the Internet protocol suite model and in the Session Layer of the OSI Model. The session layer of the OSI Model is responsible for creating and managing sessions and is the first layer that passes data.
HTML is in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 71):

> *In which layer is HTTP in the OSI model?*

It's in the **application layer**. See the following quotes from the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), one of the documents that currently defines the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

> The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is a stateless application-level request/response protocol that uses extensible semantics and self-descriptive message payloads for flexible interaction with network-based hypertext information systems.

> HTTP is a stateless request/response protocol that operates by exchanging messages across a reliable transport- or session-layer "connection".

---

> *Also some said that HTTP has no concept of session. Does it mean that HTTP can't be in the session layer?*

As previously mentioned in the quotes from the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), the HTTP protocol is **stateless**, where each request from client to server (should) contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, without taking advantage of any stored context on the server.

The [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) defines some mechanisms for state management in HTTP, such as cookies, allowing session management on server side (but it doesn't make HTTP stateful in any ways).

The concept of *session* in HTTP is different from the concept of *session* in the OSI model. Anyways, **HTTP is an application layer protocol**.

### The OSI model

The OSI (Open Systems Interconnection) model is a **conceptual model** created by the International Organization for Standardization which enables diverse communication systems to communicate using standard protocols.

It provides a standard for different computer systems to be able to communicate with each other and can be seen as a universal language for computer networking. It’s based on the concept of splitting up a communication system into seven abstract layers, each one stacked upon the last.

The following picture [borrowed from Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/glossary/open-systems-interconnection-model-osi/) illustrates pretty well what the OSI model is like:

[image: The OSI model]

The application layer is the only layer that directly interacts with data from the user. So software applications like web browsers and email clients rely on the application layer to initiate communications.

But it should be made clear that client software applications *are not part of the application layer*: rather the application layer is responsible for the protocols (such as HTTP and SMTP) and data manipulation that the software relies on to present meaningful data to the user.

### The OSI model vs the TCP/IP model

While the OSI model is comprehensive reference framework for general networking systems, it's important to mention that the modern Internet doesn’t *strictly* follow the OSI model.

The modern Internet more closely follows the simpler *Internet protocol suite*, which is commonly known as *TCP/IP* because the foundational protocols in the suite are the *TCP* (Transmission Control Protocol) and the *IP* (Internet Protocol).

The following image illustrates how the OSI and TCP/IP models relate to each other:

[image: OSI model vs TCP/IP]

---

> <sup>**Update:** This section has been added to address the bounty started by [noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1459669), who requested to update this answer with HTTP/2 details.</sup>

Despite the quotes of the document that defines the HTTP/1.1 protocol, all of the above also applies to HTTP/2. Refer to the following quote from the [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540), the document that defines the HTTP/2 protocol:

> An HTTP/2 connection is an application-layer protocol running on top of a TCP connection. The client is the TCP connection initiator.

Comment: I want to emphazize that the OSI model is a reference model. It's not a standard to base upon, especialy for layers 5 to 7. HTTP can also be considered as a presentation layer protocol. It does not do "Human-computer interaction" by itself, but the html agent uses HTTP to transfer the data.

Comment: So, Would it be correct to consider that HTTP is responsible for both application and presentation layer? Encoding and encryption (https) are part of presentation layer, right? and those are configured as part of http/s protocol

Comment: @MikelSanVicente Not really. The presentation layer does not exist in the TPP/IP model.

Comment: right, but what if we are talking about OSI model? conceptually would it be both?

Comment: @MikelSanVicente In the OSI model, the presentation layer is for compression and encryption protocols. Some of the protocols that fit in this layer are SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) and TLS (Transport Layer Security). HTTP/HTTPS sit on the top of them, still on the presentation layer.

Comment: HTTP is in the Application layer of the Internet protocol suite model and in the Session Layer of the OSI Model.

Comment: @NickAbbot What makes you think HTTP is in the session layer or the OSI Model?

Comment: @cassiomolin The purpose of the Session Layer is to provide the means necessary for cooperating presentation-entities to organize and to synchronize their dialogue and to manage their data exchange. HTTP, FTP, Telnet, all in the Session layer of OSI Model.

Comment: @cassiomolin Further, the Presentation Layer provides for common representation of the data transferred between application entities. XML, HTML, JSON, REST, MD5,...all in the presentation layer of OSI Model. Any server expecting a date from any client will receive it correctly when in JSON format.

Comment: Given http3 will be over udp, does this change things?

Answer (score -2):

The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP), is the **Web’s application-layer protocol**,
is at the heart of the Web. It is defined in **[RFC 1945] and [RFC 2616]**.

Comment: Those were obsoleted nearly half a decade ago by RFC 7230 though 7235

Comment: The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) is a stateless application-
level protocol <---- written in RFC 7230

Comment: That doesn't make your references any less obsolete.

Answer (score -3):

HTTP is in the **Application layer of the Internet protocol suite model** and in the **Session Layer of the OSI Model**. The Session layer of the OSI Model is responsible for creating and managing sessions and is the first layer that passes data.

HTTP can redirect sessions, reuse them and have persistent connections.

Comment: HTTP sessions are not the same as session layer of OSI

Comment: If you read the definition you'll find that they do the same thing.